# Team-owned repository URLs include *creator's* username, not team's

Tags: bitbucket

A while back, I created an individual account and a few repositories. Today I created a team account for my employer and transferred ownership of my repositories to that account. Logically, the repositories belong to the company, not just me. At some point I'll add my boss and coworkers as members of the team account.

One thing is bothering me, though. The URLs of the transferred repositories are still of the form https://<my-individual-username>@bitbucket.org/.... Can I change the username to the team username?

Edit: An additional detail: When I go to change the team ID (username), Bitbucket warns me that, "Renaming this team will change the URLs of X repositories," and links to the repositories I recently transferred. The warning is incorrect. Renaming the team ID has no effect, but renaming the creator does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLs you see contain your username because they are used to authenticate as you. If someone else views the repository the URL should contain their username.

Comment: Oh my god... I knew that. I did. I just... Thank you. (・_・;)

Comment: it's the little things that get you ;)